# jquerymobile phonegap back-button get previous state

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm building an little mobile app and I got a question about JQM.

When the user is logged in the user will be redirected to page A. Page A is loaded with the loadPage from JQM (example: `$.mobile.loadPage("pageA.html")`)

After the page is loaded, I do an AJAX-call because I pull some data from a database and change the content on page A. From page A, I can go to page B. page B has an back-button. When I click on the back-button, the app slides back to the state without the AJAX content. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, jQuery Mobile will remove any page brought into the DOM via AJAX once the user navigates away from the page. If you want to disable this feature for a specific page you can add the `data-dom-cache` attribute to the `data-role="page` element for the page and set it to `true`:

```
<div data-dom-cache="true" data-role="page" id="pageA">
    ...
</div>
```

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-cache.html*

This feature was added to jQuery Mobile to help control the size of the DOM so less browser crashes will occur. If you just want to keep a single page in the DOM then make sure it's not a huge page that will bog-down the device.

Comment: Allright, Thanks. Works perfect. I looked in every page of the JQM docs, never saw this :) maybe I need glasses ;)

Comment: @Blynn Yeah this should work fine with PhoneGap. In PhoneGap you are using a `webview` to display your webpage inside an application. So most of the same basic DOM exists.

Comment: Yes, getting a document from the internet is fine in a mobile application. It's treated as a normal AJAX request. Since there is no origin domain on a mobile device there aren't cross-domain-policy issues. Although you may want to read the jQuery Mobile documentation regarding PhoneGap applications (it's under Page -> PhoneGap).

Comment: 10000+++ you made my day. Life saver. Thank yoU! :D